# adding bounce animation to date picker

Tags: datepicker, bounce

I have a date picker using jquery. However I want to add the 'bounce' animation to it. Please help me adding this animation to the date picker. My code as of now is:

```
$(function() {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({ dateFormat: "DD, d MM, yy" });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are trying to accomplish?

```
$(function() {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({ showAnim: "bounce", dateFormat: "DD, d MM, yy" });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/damyanpetev/VS2hV/

Additionally you can set [duration](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-duration) and [additional options](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-showOptions) that correspond to the effect you are using (in this case ['bounce'](http://api.jqueryui.com/bounce-effect/) .

Comment: Yes Damyah. Thanks a lot. That is what, I was exactly expecting.